# POST request between javascript in website and node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, web

I need to send the data from an HTML form using a javascript function to a node.js server running at the same address.
For the record, i have a website hosted on my Raspberry PI, using a custom domain.
This is the javascript function:

```
$.post("http://www.website.com:2052/form", formData, function(data){
    ...
    console.log("POST SUCCESS");
    ...
});
```

This is the code for my node.js server:

```
app.post('/form', function(req, res){
    ....
    console.log('POST - body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send({result:"success"});
    ....
});
```

When i send the form data to the server, i receive it on the server, but i get this on website-side:

```
Failed to load http://www.website.com:2052/form: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.website.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I understand that i need to add the access control header in the response, but considering they are on the same "ip", why is it needed? Or how can i make the node.js server actually appear on the same domain?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to include the port number on access control header ?

Comment: `app.use(cors())` https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this to your node.js server:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});
```

You can check out documentation for:

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: Thank i will try it now